# Delete folder’s contents recursively but keep folder

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm looking to delete all contents of a directory recursively (except for one file) but keep the folder itself. I've written this task to do so:

```
gulp.task('clean:documentation', function () {
    del([
        'documentation.typography/**',
        '!documentation.typography/.gitignore'
    ]);
});
```

Unfortunately it removes the entire folder. What's wrong with this task? How can I update so it removes everything in `documentation.typography` *except* for the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Enable option.dot ? https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/932

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to change the glob:

```
gulp.task('clean:documentation', function () {
    del([
        'documentation.typography/**/*',
        '!documentation.typography/.gitignore'
    ]);
});
```